# is there any javascript code that click automatically in text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wanna asking about if there is any javascript code that click automatically on a text field ! i wanna just that the input text will be clicked automatically  to update the output text

```
 <h:inputText id="text" value="#{lq.question}">
 <f:ajax render="out5" event="click"istener="#{speechBean.getQuestionName1(lq.question)}">
</f:ajax>
</h:inputText>
<h:outputText id="out5"value="#{speechBean.questionName}"></h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the `focus` method on the element in question.

```js
document.getElementById('text').focus();
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" />
```

Comment: Just barely :) - probably the jquery reference.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can trigger the `onfocus` event to "click inside a text field"

Since you added [jQuery] as one of your tags, I'll use it in an example:

```js
$("textarea").focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

You can also use plain JS to trigger it, as in @colecmc's answer.